# Is this an acceptable way to find an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

I have a matrix *M* where 
$$ 
M = \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 1 & 2 \\
        -3 & -6 & -7 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and it has an eigenvector of $\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
        -1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

I am trying to find the corresponding eigenvalue but I am not sure if it is the correct way to do it. My working is shown below:
$$\begin{align}
(M - \lambda I)\cdot x & = 0 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
        -2 - \lambda & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 1 - \lambda & 2 \\
        -3 & -6 & -7 - \lambda\\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
        -1  \\
        \end{pmatrix} & = 0 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        1 - \lambda -2  \\
        -6 + 7 + \lambda  \\
        \end{pmatrix} & = 0 \\
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $1- \lambda - 2 = 0$ or $-6 + 7 + \lambda = 0$ so  $\lambda = -1$

Please correct me if my presentation isn't right.

Comment: Why not just multiply $M$ by the eigenvector? You know that for an eigenvector $\vec{v}$ of $M$, $M\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$, so just look to see what number each of the two non-zero entries in your eigenvector have been multiplied by.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the feedback! @BenS.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the definition $M\cdot V=\lambda V$

In our case

$$M\cdot V=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}=-V$$

So the eigenvalue is $-1$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it!